# c++, Create Anonymous SubClass Object in Abstract Class

Tags: c++, abstract-class, subclass, anonymous-objects

I have an Abstract Class and I need to create two anonymous subclasses objects for it. I have multiple subclasses. Just write the code to create one of these objects

Comment: what is an anonymous object?

Comment: I have six subclasses. Anonymous as in, it will be one of those six subclass objects

Answer (score 3):

When you declare a class (or structure) the name of the class optional if you declare a variable, but you can still use inheritance.

Something like

```
class AbstractBaseClass
{
public:
    virtual void abstract_function() = 0;
};

class : public AbstractBaseClass
{
public:
    void abstract_function() { ... }
} my_anonymous_object;
```

Comment: Ok but how do I then make the object in my abstract class?